# Unable to access loaded assemblies across AppDomains

Tags: c#, appdomain

**Give this load assembly code:**

```
public class LoadAssembly : MarshalByRefObject, ILoadAssembly
{
    private readonly AppDomain currentDomain;
    public LoadAssembly()
    {
        currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    }

    public void LoadFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        //currentDomain has no assemblies:
        Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
        //currentDomain has assemblies:

    }
}
```

**Given the following test:**

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test", null,
new AppDomainSetup
{
    ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile,
    ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    ShadowCopyFiles = "false"
});
var t = typeof(LoadAssembly);

//appDomain has no assemblies.
var loader = (ILoadAssembly)appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(t.Assembly.Location, t.FullName);

loader.LoadFromFile("some path to a correct dll.");

//issue appDomain still has no assemblies.
```

I am trying to load assemblies into a new AppDomain.

Then assert that they all of the assemblies have been loaded into the new AppDomain.

I can see that inside of LoadAssembly.LoadFromFile, currentDomain has my loaded assemblies;

However, when I try to use the appDomain outside of my LoadAssembly class, it has no loaded assemblies that I am expecting. Any ideas?

---

var appDomain; the manual (proxy) one doesn't have my assemblies, outside the instance of the class.

Comment: Yes it seem to be reasonable to be able to enumerate assemblies in any domain. On other hand I'm sort of expecting such behavior (as parent domain not necessary will be able to load assembly the same way as child AppDomain loaded) but I can't see any explanation.

Comment: @Andrew Where is the assembly you are trying to load located? Is it in the application base path or the private bin path? I tested your sample and it worked fine. Why don't you add the code you used for your test too.